# GNOME application startup latency - reasons

Tags: gnome, latency

When starting applications under Debian and GNOME I get big startup latencies. Even a simple calculator or a tiny text editor need around 1 second until they show a window. What happens during this time? The only application being faster is the clock which still has noticeable latency but not a big one.

Under Windows I do not know such a behaviour. Every small programm is ready immediately after having clicked the start icon. I notice this problem since decades under Linux regardless of what distribution or desktop environment. While Windows is ready Linux does something...

But WHAT?

Thanks in advance for any explanation and of course any idea what can be done agianst this as it's a useless waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of things. What's the machine you're running on? What services do you have running?

If you have your /home directory on a separate partition, particularly an HDD, you will experience slowdown even if your boot is on an SSD, since programs store their settings in /home.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It has always been the same on any Linux I have ever seen. Even very small programs showed latancy while starting - regardless of what machine it was running on. To answer your question: It's Debian 11 with GNOME 40 on Windows 10 inside VMware Player 16. And: Windows 10 inside VM does not schow any latency, it is not a general problem of my setup.

Comment: On a fresh Windows install? This could be. It's to do with the fact that windows does a lot of preloading/fetching stuff into RAM, including your most commonly used apps, whereas Linux does not. This could be the cause of the slight latency you're experiencing. It could also be to do with where your partitions physically lie; if you're on an HDD, partitions towards the centre of the disk have much slower read/write speeds than the outside. I think you'll find though that as the installs age, Linux will do much better than Windows in general (win registry and user files tend to get overinflated

Comment: Thanks for telling your thoughts. Maybe I was not clear enough. I am a programmer that has deeper knowledge of what happens while starting a program under Windows - but I do not know what happens under Debian/GNOME. On Windows for example when opening calc.exe a VERY short EXE is copied into memory, some initialisation may be done and immediately afterwards the code instrucst the Windows API to create and show the application window. There is absolutely not a single reason that the whole process should last longer than 50 ms.

Comment: And Windows does not need a single ms longer. So the question remains: How can a so called modern OS like Debian 11 waste 950 ms? Does it cook a coffee during it's actions? All this runs on a SSD and even on harddisks there could only be 50 ms more. There is a step or some steps that waste time. Maybe it uses a hundred libraries for every small program and has to connect to them in any way? Til now I have no real understanding where this comes from. It bothers me since MANY years and I had always hoped that someone would solve this... Now I think about solving it by myself. Maybe you can help.

Comment: I'm struggling to find evidence of the general slowness you are referring to. For example if I time the startup of a simple calculator:
`
time kcalc :
real    0m4.296s 
user    0m0.179s 
sys     0m0.017s 
`
You can see the total time the kernel spends loading the application is 17ms. the user time is to do with the individual apps startup process with all its libraries. 17ms seems pretty fast to me. Could it be to do with the drivers on your VM?